# Interpolar urls en css-loader de webpack

Tags: css, webpack

Estoy empezando a usar `webpack` y lo estoy aplicando a algo sencillo pero tengo un problema.

Al utilizar el plugin `mini-css-extract-plugin` con `css-loader` me arroja un error debido a que no puede cargar un `.png` que estoy usando para `background-image`, ya que no he instalado ningún `loader` para ese tipo de archivos (supongo)

¿Como podrìa simplemente interpolar esa **url**, para que `webpack` no cargue el archivo `png` sino solo se pase la **url** como una cadena?

Aquí coloco mi configuración:

```js
const path = require("path");
const miniCSSExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/js/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js")
  },

  plugins: [
    new miniCSSExtractPlugin({
      filename: "../css/main.css"
    })
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: [miniCSSExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: ¿Podés poner un repo donde mirarle así le construyo y le arreglo?

Comment: Lo solucione utilizando gulp con node-sass para compilar los archivos css, muchas graciaass amigo @deividsito